# Insert number into String fast, by .format or .replace?

Tags: java, string, replace, formatting, string-formatting

I just want to set a placeholder in a String to a running number in a big loop. For convenience the placeholder is `%d`. What is faster, using String's .format or .replace method?

Comment: Have you tried both? What were your results? Is it possible to format the number to a fixed number of digits? (If so, creating a char array to reuse may well help...) Basically you haven't provided enough information here yet. A [mcve] showing what you've done so far, along with your concrete performance requirements, would really help.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was concentrating to much on coding and though just to throw this question into the room. I'm sorry I forgot about the guidelines, really need to think my questions through...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I didn't know the response but I was curious about it I did a very simple test and add metrics and those are the results:

The code:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    String original = "This is the phrase %d";
    long init = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        System.out.println(String.format(original, i));
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long init1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        System.out.println(original.replace("%d", String.valueOf(i)));
    }
    long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Method 1: " + (end-init));
    System.out.println("Method 2: " + (end2-init1));
}
```

The results

> Method 1: 1950 Method 2: 1361

So we can assume .replace is faster than String's format method

Comment: Here's some reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: @Kayaman thanks! is the best time i do a benchmark I will do next properly :)

Comment: I suspect there are far quicker options as well, working out where the format string is, and creating an appropriate `char[]`, then just replacing the relevant characters each time.